# Using intellij to modify/build/index code base on remote system

Tags: intellij-idea, build, project

I have 2 machines to work upon. One is my macbook pro which I prefer for development purpose and another is a remote machine where I do majority of my testing by building the code base and bootstrapping the application.

Is there a way by which I can configure intellij on my mac to point the code base in remote machine so that Intellij can easily identify the project structure and build artefacts there? By this way I am assuming that intellij will not build the code base locally, rather it will just index already build files and help me in modifying the code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [has no support for that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110822) at the moment.